# Is it even safe to persist the IAP in iCloud?

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase, icloud

My case is annual subscription for full functionality which falls into non-renewing subscription IAP category.

> Information about consumable products and non-renewing subscriptions
>   is added to the receipt when they’re paid for and remains in the
>   receipt until you finish the transaction. After you finish the
>   transaction, this information is removed the next time the receipt is
>   updated—for example, the next time the user makes a purchase.

If I'm getting it right, once I retrieve the receipt, successfully validate and persist, I finish the transaction and thats it. I can no more retrieve receipt for that purchase. So I better make sure that the persistence cannot be lost or I'm screwed (actually the buyer is). But I want nobody to be screwed so I need to guarantee the persistence.

> For non-renewing subscriptions, use iCloud or your own server to keep
>   a persistent record.

Okay I have no reason to use my own server and like the idea of iCloud very much. But also getting concerned about it.

Is there an iCloud storage I can prevent records from being deleted or at least inform about about annual subscription lost prior deletion?

For IAP persistence, Key-Value storage seems to be best fit (also used as example in guide) but not that reliable as well. As far as I know, these data are not deleted together with app, but can be deleted at any time in iCloud settings. There is no other way to delete them is there? If not, I understand and agree that user should always has right to delete content in his iCloud storage. But he may not be aware of loosing his subscription. What about this?

I'm not familiar with CloudKit so far. Can it provide more convenient solution? Or is there even a way to persist that receipt for the whole subscription remaining time using iCloud?

Comment: Yes, use cloud kit as the user can't delete information from there